# Axis2 doesnt work with Dynamic Web Module 3.0

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, tomcat7

I am trying to create a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse. When I try to create a Web Service Client, it reports that only Dynamic Web Module 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5 are supported. Is there any workaround for this. I am using Dynamic Web Module 3.0 with Tomcat 7.0